# Symfony Query Builder (Many to many relation)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have question about QueryBuilder.
I have two entities: Product, Attribute, which are in many to many relations (Each Product can have many attributes, and each attribudes can have many products)
I create product repository function findByAttributes()

```
public function findByAttributes($attributes)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->join('p.attributes', 'a')
        ->where('a.slug = :slug1 OR a.slug = :slug2')
        ->setParameter('slug1', 'red')
        ->setParameter('slug2', 'blue')
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

When i use OR it work fine, but when i switch to AND result is empty.
With AND I want to select only products who have both attributes.

Where I am wrong?

Tnx

Comment: `a.slug` can't be equal to two different strings at the same time, are you sure there is no issue here ?

Comment: Hmm... i want do select only products who have both attributes

Comment: `a.slug` is what ? a string ? An array ? Your where condition says: a.slug = 'red' and a.slug = 'blue', how is that possible at the same time?

Comment: a.slug is a string. Each product cant have many attributes.

Comment: Then don't you see the issue here ? you want to be able to check if a.slug is equals to two different string at the same time. You say you want  *to select only products who have both attributes*, how is that possible ? Is there multiple slug property ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
public function findByAttributes(array $attributes)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

    foreach ($attributes as $i => $attribute) {
        $qb->join('p.attributes', 'a'.$i)
           ->andWhere('a'.$i.'.slug = :slug'.$i.'')
           ->setParameter('slug'.$i, $attribute);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).